# Problem with merging columns in two different ways

Tags: tables

I'm writing a tabular which is actually a form to print and be filled by hand. I want to set fixed column width. The problem comes when I try to merge columns in two different patterns. 
I can't draw the table in Markdown, so I'll describe it. It's a 4 columns x 5 rows table.
In the first two  rows I want to merge the second and third columns, in the last three rows I want to merge the first with the second column and the third with the fourth column. But what I get is the second, third and fourth columns merged in the last three rows (I get the first two rows exactly as I want them).

I wrote this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ | p{52mm}  p{21mm}  p{32mm}  p{41mm} | }
\hline
Nome e cognome & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Luogo e data di nascita} & Comune di iscrizione nelle liste \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}& Trezzano sul Naviglio \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Firma} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Documento}   \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}  \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix my code to get what I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Normally the best way to show a problem is to take a screenshot of the output, in cases like yours. Also please add a tag like `tabular`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you never use any of the original columns, so apparently `tabular` forgets about these widths. So you would have to specify at least once the width of the merged columns in the third or a subsequent row.
I guess you also would like to have some `\hline`s between the rows.

And you probably need some wider paper to fit the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ | p{52mm}  p{21mm}  p{32mm}  p{41mm} | }
\hline
Nome e cognome & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Luogo e data di nascita} & Comune di iscrizione nelle liste \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}& Trezzano sul Naviglio \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{73mm}|}{Firma} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Documento}   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]